# C++/Qt: Just a LNK2019 and I don't know why

Tags: c++, qt, lnk2019

I have one of this unpopular LNK2019-errors in my project. Perhaps anyone can help me?

That's my header file:

```
#ifndef ELIST_H
#define ELIST_H

#include <QTableWidget>

class EList : public QTableWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit EList(QWidget *parent = 0){}
    ~EList(){}
};

#endif // ELIST_H
```

and that's another cpp-file, where I want to create an object of EList in method do():

```
#include "elist.h"
#include "a.h"

void A::do(){
    EList* el = new EList;
}
```

But then I get this LNK2019 error message:
a.obj:-1: Error:LNK2019: ""public: __cdecl EList::EList(class QWidget *)" (??0EList@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)" in function ""public: __cdecl A::A(class QWidget *)" (??0A@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)".

What did I wrong or what I have to do? I have insert all files/classes I could imagine but it did not show any effect.

---

EDIT: Here you can see my pro-File:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = A
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        a.cpp \
    elist.cpp

HEADERS  += a.h \
    elist.h

FORMS    += a.ui

RESOURCES += \
    ListViewIcon.qrc
```

And if I change Compiler (Qt 5.1 MSVC 2012) to Microsoft (Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 11.0), all files will compiled...

Comment: What are you using to build this and can you post the qmake file or Makefile?

Comment: Original, I want to override mouseDoubleClickEvent(), so I can react to double click on an instance of QTableWidget. This Widget I want to create in an extra window (A). For building I using QtCreator.

Comment: But qmake file is an executable file? How should I post it?

Comment: If you use qmake. You should have a .pro file. Post that.

Comment: Ok. I changed compiler and now I can continue my work. Nevertheless I still wonder why the other compiler doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained code. That is, a simple main.cpp which reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

With C++ code, you generally can't mix-and-match compilers. Whatever C++ compiler was used to build Qt is what you should be using to build your application. You've basically answered your own question :)